# onLost in NetworkCallback doesn't work when I launch the app

Tags: android, kotlin

It works when I turn off the internet in the app but it doesn't work when I launch the app without the internet

```
private val networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback =
    object: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            //setButtonEnabled(true)
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            //setButtonEnabled(false)
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: What's the use-case here? Enabling or disabling a button as per your code? Can't you start with the button disabled by default and everything would then work as expected with your current code? The reason i am asking is because you're more or less doing things "correctly" as per what Android is looking for. I would not recommend doing things synchronously using deprecated APIS:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()

Comment: @Sasha Arutyunyan,  Hi, if the answer helps you, please also vote it, make it help more other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `NetworkCallback`  according to the network change to give you a callback.

the class [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) says as follows:

> Base class for NetworkRequest callbacks. Used for notifications about network changes

if you want to check if the network is available you can use the following code

```
    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    val isConnected: Boolean = activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true
```

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing the same thing. If I launch the app without a network connection neither `NetworkCallback.onLost` or `NetworkCallback.onUnavailable` are called. Yet if I launch the app with a network connection, `NetworkCallback.onAvailable` *is* called.

Seems like a ConnectivityManager bug to me honestly. I added a work around that checks if the activeNetwork is null at the time I setup the callback, and if it is, I just run the logic that I normally would if the callback told me the network is unavailable. This seems to handle it for me.

```
val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        // Run my onAvailable code
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        // Run my onLost code
    }

    override fun onUnavailable() {
        // Run my onUnavailable code
    }
}
connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)

// !!! Added this !!!
// There appears to be an issue where neither NetworkCallback.onLost or NetworkCallback.onUnavailable
// are called if the app is started without a network connection; because of this we cannot
// rely on the callback correctly initializing if offline. Work around here 
// by checking activeNetwork immediately.
if (connectivityManager.activeNetwork == null) {
    // Run my onUnavailable code
}
```